# javascript which reads file stops setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, settimeout

in my code I have a weird problem.. I have this basic code which works and gives me what I expect:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function () { myfunc('0', '0'); }, 1000);
</script>
```

I am trying to use variables instead of '0' '0', I read these variables from a text file, and then I've modify the script accordingly but in the log console I see that setTimeout is not called anymore as before.. any idea?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    file = fopen(getScriptPath("myfile"), 0);

    if (file != -1) {
        file_length = flength(file);
        content = fread(file, file_length);

        fileLines = content.split("\n");
        lines = fileLines.length;

        // I skip the header lines (1 and 2)
        for (i = 2; i <= lines; i++) {
            chn = fileLines[i].split("_");
            values = fileLines[i].split(" ");

            if (values[3] == 1) {
                if (chn[1] == "t1") {
                    var1 = values[1];
                    var2 = values[2];
                    setTimeout(function () { myfunc(var1, var2); }, 1000);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    // Even if I put the function here it is not called unless I comment all the rest!
    //setTimeout(function() {myfunc(var1,var2);}, 1000);
</script>
```

myfile has this kind of structure:

```
header1
header2
text_t1 0 0 1
text_t2 0 1 1
text_t3 0 2 1
```

Comment: What platform does this execute on? A browser? Node.Js? Rhino? Normally you can't do synchronous file I/O like that, and in browsers you can't at all (without some of the newer APIs)

Comment: This is running under a simple apache/opensuse server and I've tried to browse the page with mozilla/chrome. I do not really need to read the file asynchronously but at least the first time the script is launched. I don't know very well javascript but I thought (as PHP) was possible to read a file in an "easy" way.. what do you suggest?

Comment: I think you've confused PHP and JavaScript a little. The code above appears to be a mix of both languages within the same script tag. That won't work. Your PHP needs to be a .php file on the server side, and your JavaScript script tag needs to be within an .html file served to the client side (by the apache server).

Comment: The file operations are indeed easy in PHP, but they'd run on the server, not the browser. Why do you need the JavaScript? What's the setTimeout for ?

Comment: Actually I need that piece of javascript to implement ajax (and that's the reason why I have the setTimmeout), I thought that I could somehow modify my ajax template call inserting an I/O.. since I would like to pass to the PHP code which run async some variables that the javascript will find on a file. (Actually one could say why don't you read the file in the PHP but I want to keep it general and just receive externally those variables, if it is possible..)

Comment: No, it's not possible to mix the languages, and client-vs-server side in that way.

Comment: I see.. is there another way to do what I intended to do..?

Comment: You should have two separate files, the PHP (server-side) and HTML (client-side), both served from your Apache. The HTML should contain JavaScript which uses AJAX to talk to the PHP file's URL. The PHP script should do the file-reading operations. There is no practical way to do that on the browser.